# Trying to Understand TFS 2017 Label Changeset

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I'm trying to understand the "Changeset" that TFS 2017 uses when I create a label after a build/release. For a simple example, I did the following:

1. Created Main and Dev folders
2. Created a TestWebApp project, checked-in to Main as a baseline
3. Created a Dev branch from Main
4. Made some modifications in the Dev branch
5. Merged the Dev branch back to Main and checked-in
6. Decided a hotfix was needed in the middle of the test cycle, so I rolled back the Dev merge, made a hotfix change, and checked-in to Main
7. Labeled Main at this point to represent the Hotfix release
8. Re-merged the changes from Dev
9. Decided another hotfix was needed, so I rolled back the Dev marge again, made a hotfix change and checked-in to Main
10. Labeled Main at this point to represent the Hotfix release
11. Re-merged the changes from Dev again

Below is a screenshot of the changesets I made in TFS:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the labels I made:

[image]

My question is: Why do the labels all show Changeset 6 when the 2nd and 3rd releases included changes made since Changeset 6?

Answer (score 0):

That's because most of files in the Main folder are still in the Changeset 6. If you navigate the file that changed during this process, check the history and label, and you'll find it points to the latest changeset.

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me why it chose Changeset 6 when Changesets 11 and 16 were labeled.

Comment: If you click the label, and expend the main folder, you'll see the changeset for each file, most files are still has changeset 6, only the modified file has the new changset.